# Tracking a file independent of Git branches

Tags: git

I use Git for version control of my work projects. I tend to maintain a Python file in which I test small samples of code before implementing those ideas into my main code. Like everyone, I create a new branch when working on creating a new feature. However, this test file, let's call it `scratchpad`, will continue to grow as I work on different features. I am looking for ideas to maintain this scratchpad. Should I keep this file as part of the master branch? or something else? I thought about not including the file in any of the branches by adding it to gitignore, but then the file won't be backed up anywhere. I view Git as also a tool to backup my code(s) to remote repository.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the purpose of this `srcatchpad` file? To keep notes pertaining to the project? If so, just use the project's `readme.md`. Obviously if it contains sensitive project information and your repository is public, you'd want to just use a local (non-committed) file instead. But 'code tests' should really simply just be tested locally -- once you are happy that the code works, go ahead and commit it. If it doesn't work, don't commit it, and just keep the notes local.

Comment: No, the only purpose of this `scratchpad` file is to test different code ideas. I find it useful to keep all the code snippets, tricks, etc. in one place (`scratchpad`) and glance over it once in a while to refresh memory. How do people achieve this otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle associated to that scratchpad is very different from your project development.

So simply maintain its history in a separate Git repository, that you can checkout in a different folder *outside* of your project local repo.
You IDE can have both your project and that file opened at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a file related to your project that contains notes you can use across branches- it is better to just keep a local copy of that file on your machine and refer to it whenever you need to add/look at/remove notes. There is no reason to add it to your project repository. I keep notes on a physical notebook or on an individual separate file on my computer. I don't push it anywhere online. If you are worried about backing data up- there are more ways to do that than just pushing everything you want backed up to git. And if you are using an online tool like github you can use gist or something similar. Why clutter your project with notes?

If you want a file related to your project that contains notes that you want to use across branches AND you want other contributors to use across branches- you should put that file in whichever branch people create new branches off of. For most projects- this would be master. Some repositories have secondary branch off of master (mainly for testing). Put the file on whichever branch people branch off of- so that whenever someone pushes to the development branch- if they made changes to the notes they can push them to this branch and when others pull from the development branch- they will see the new notes.